# Custom RESTful route within has_many nesting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

**Projects** have many **tasks** and a task has a custom RESTful action called 'approve'.

I'm expecting the helper to look something like this **approve_project_task_url**

This isn't working for me:

```
map.resources :projects,
              :has_many => :tasks,
                           :member => { :approve => :post }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I once had the same problem but I never searched long and hard for a fix. Instead I just opted for the older style which since then I've always used:

```
map.resources :projects do |project|
  project.resources :tasks, :member => {:approve => :post}
end
```

That will give you your required `approve_project_task_url(@project, @task)` routes/helpers.

I guess you may already know this approach? If so and you don't like it hopefully I'll learn something from your other responses :)

Comment: You can also use "rake routes" to see what routes have been created.

Comment: That is the fix.  :has_many is just a shortcut for when it's not complicated.

Answer (score 1):

```
 **This is syntax correction to above solution**

map.resources :projects do |project|
  project.resources :tasks, :member => {:approve => :post}
end
```